# How to disable UIView Layer resize bounds animation in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, uiviewanimation

when I try to process an animation of UIView to make GLKView fit the screen,

the layer of GLKView was fine, but the OpenGL image of GLKView was being smaller then fit to size.

How can I make it no more smaller, just transform from origin size to new size ?

> original size of opengl image

[image]

> process an uiview animation to make opengl image fit the screen (I don't want the image being smaller when animation processing)

[image]

> new size of opengl image

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to use UIImageView

```
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"your image"];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: It's a video application, render YUV by OpenGL